# R plot3d coloring

Tags: r, rgl

I am using `plot3d()` from `rgl` to make 3D scatter plots, using three columns, of samples in a data frame. Furthermore, I am using a fourth column `colorby` from my data frame (where each sample takes values, say, 10, 11, 12 as factors/levels) to color the points in the plot.

When using `plot()` to make 2D plots, I first set `palette(rainbow(3))` and then `col = colorby` within `plot()` followed by `legend()`. The plot, colors and legend work fine.

However, when I repeat the last part for `plot3d()`, the coloring mixes up and not the same colors are assigned to the same levels as they would be in `plot()`. Moreover, if I use `legend3d("topright", legend = levels(colorby), col = rainbow(3))` to create a legend, it looks the same as the 2D legend, but the coloring is clearly wrong in the 3D plot.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks correct to me:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:9, y=9:1, z=101:109, colorby=gl(3,3))
palette(rainbow(3))
plot(x~y, df, col = df$colorby)
library(rgl)
with(df, plot3d(x,y,z, col = colorby))
legend3d("topright", legend = levels(df$colorby), col = levels(df$colorby), pch=19)
```

Comment: That worked fine indeed. I noticed that for my `legend3d()` code, I used `col = 1:length(df$colorby)` which gives a _different_ and _incorrect_ legend as opposed to using `col = levels(df$colorby)`. Any idea why?

Comment: Those are two different vectors.  Why would you expect them to be the same?  Yours gives 1:9, lukeA's gives c("1", "2", "3").  The fact that the second is a character vector doesn't matter, the fact that they contain different values does.